# Email responses from Google forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

How can I automate the process of periodically sending an email of batch of responses on my google form?

I believe google script can be of help, but not sure how to go about? Any heads up would be a great help.

Comment: You can configure this in response tab in google forms

Answer (score -1):

There is an add-on in google forms called [Form Notifications](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/form-notifications/bbpdeojefjfhaelgljjcadpcckdfcdod) which will send automatic response after the submission.

And [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/editors/forms/quickstart/forms-notifications) is the sample Documentation for form notifications in app scripts